# Is there anything wrong with creating AutoMappper mappings in the view model static constructor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

Well? For example, I often do this:

```
public class PersonEditModel: MappedViewModel<Person>
{
    static PersonEditModel()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonEditModel>().Bidirectional();
    }
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public LanguageCompetencyIndexModel Languages { get; set; }
}
```

I have a little helper stashed in my core set of MVC add-ins:

```
public static void Bidirectional<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<TDestination, TSource>();
}
```

It saves creating a second mapping and is great for simple capture/display scenarios.

Now, instead of creating maps elsewhere, at `App_Start` or somewhere, I can put this view model in a library and use it anywhere, without having to remember to add a mapping for it.

Comment: I used to do this, and would occasionally run into automapper missing mapping configuration exceptions, though I could never pin down exactly why. Moving the mapping declarations back to `App_Start` solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to re-use mapping definitions, put them in a [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825244/where-to-place-automapper-createmaps).  It removes the Automapper dependency from your view models and allows you to easily centralize your mappings.