# Multiple AutoMapper.Configure() in Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I am using AutoMapper to map between DTO objects and my business objects. I've two AutoMapperConfiguration.cs files - one in my service layer and another one in my web api layer.

As shown in the answer at the following link 
[Where to place AutoMapper.CreateMaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825244/where-to-place-automapper-createmaps)

I am calling the Configure() of both these files in my Global.asax class

```
AutoMapperWebConfiguration.Configure();
AutoMapperServiceConfiguration.Configure();
```

but it seems like the my Service Configure call (the second call) is overwriting the mappings of the web api layer (the first call) and I get an exception saying the Mapping is missing.

If I reverse the Configure calls to look like this

```
AutoMapperServiceConfiguration.Configure();
AutoMapperWebConfiguration.Configure();
```

I don't get the exception for web api mapping but I get the same mapping exception for the Service layer.

Am I doing something wrong because this is clearly marked as an answer in the above stack overflow link?

Here's my code:

```
public static class AutoMapperServiceConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile<CmciFlowTestToGenericFlowTestSimpleMappingProfile>();
            x.AddProfile<FsrsFlowTestToGenericFlowTestSimpleMappingProfile>();
        });
    }
}

public class FsrsFlowTestToGenericFlowTestSimpleMappingProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<FsrsFlowTest, GenericFlowTest>()
            .ConvertUsing<FsrsFlowTestToGenericFlowTestSimpleConverter>();
    }
}

public class FsrsFlowTestToGenericFlowTestSimpleConverter : TypeConverter<FsrsFlowTest, GenericFlowTest>
{
    protected override GenericFlowTest ConvertCore(FsrsFlowTest source)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return new GenericFlowTest
            {
                FlowTestDate = source.FlowTestDates,
                StaticPsi = source.HydrantStaticPsi.ToString(),
                ResidualPsi = source.HydrantResidualPsi.ToString(),
                TotalFlow = source.NffGallonsPerMinute.ToString(),
                FlowTestLocation = source.FsrsFlowTestLocations.Any()
                          ? source.FsrsFlowTestLocations.First().LocationDescription
                          : null
            };
    }

public class CmciFlowTestToGenericFlowTestSimpleMappingProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<CmciFlowTest, GenericFlowTest>()
            .ConvertUsing<CmciFlowTestToGenericFlowTestSimpleConverter>();
    }
}

public class CmciFlowTestToGenericFlowTestSimpleConverter : TypeConverter<CmciFlowTest, GenericFlowTest>
{
    protected override GenericFlowTest ConvertCore(CmciFlowTest source)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return new GenericFlowTest
            {
                FlowTestDate = source.FlowTestDates,
                StaticPsi = source.HydrantStaticPsi.ToString(),
                ResidualPsi = source.HydrantResidualPsi.ToString(),
                TotalFlow = source.CalculatedHydrantGallonsPerMinute.ToString(),
                FlowTestLocation = source.StaticLocationHydrantFlowPSI
            };
    }
}    

public static class AutoMapperWebConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
            {
                x.AddProfile<ServiceToWebApiMappingProfile>();
                x.AddProfile<WebApiToServiceMappingProfile>();
            });
    }
}

public class ServiceToWebApiMappingProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<ServiceFlowTest, FlowTest>();
    }
}

public class WebApiToServiceMappingProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<PropertyAddress, ServicePropertyAddress>();
    }
}
```

To get around this issue, I am adding the service profiles in the AutoMapperWebConfiguration class and only calling AutoMapperWebConfiguration.Configure() in global.asax.

Comment: Can you post the code in the Configure methods, the mapped types and also the mappings that are failing?

Comment: Are you only calling `CreateMap` in the Configure methods?

Comment: Are you by any chance calling `Mapper.Reset();`?

Comment: @stuartd: No, I am not calling Mapper.Reset().

Comment: @GertArnold: I am using Profiles. I am calling CreateMap in my profiles. In Configure(), I am only adding profiles in Mapper.Initialize()

Comment: @GruffBunny: I will try to post the code soon.

Comment: @GruffBunny: I modified my original post by including the Mapper configuration code.

Comment: Profiles are an abstraction of the actual mappers, can you show the contents of all the profiles then it will be easier to see what's mapping to what?

Comment: @Stokedout: I've modified the original post include all the mapping code.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The calls to **Mapper.Initialize** reset the mapper so everything that's gone before is wiped.

Move the calls to AddProfile into one Mapper.Initialize call and all should be well:

```
Mapper.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.AddProfile<CmciFlowTestToGenericFlowTestSimpleMappingProfile>();
    x.AddProfile<FsrsFlowTestToGenericFlowTestSimpleMappingProfile>();
    x.AddProfile<ServiceToWebApiMappingProfile>();
    x.AddProfile<WebApiToServiceMappingProfile>();
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing right now. I am adding profiles from my service layer in my AutoMapperWebConfiguration class. I was confused due to the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825244/where-to-place-automapper-createmaps which shows multiple Configure() calls in the global.asax.

Answer (score 11):

@GruffBunny's answer is correct, but I tried to make it a bit neater for scalability (e.g. if you have many, complex `Mapper.Initialize()` methods, and might add more in the future).

I did this by implementing the following structure in **all** of my `AutoMapperConfiguration.cs` files:

#### Extract the `Action<IConfiguration>` from your existing `Mapper.Initialize()` method into a public property

I call it `ConfigAction` in each one.

```
public static Action<IConfiguration> ConfigAction = new Action<IConfiguration>(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile<SomeProfile>();            
            x.AddProfile<SomeOtherProfileProfile>();
            //... more profiles
        });
```

This allows you to invoke the action from anywhere you need to call `Mapper.Initialize`.

#### `Mapper.Initialize()` inside `Configure()` now just references this property

```
public static void Configure()
{
    Mapper.Initialize(ConfigAction);
}
```

You can then invoke all your different `ConfigAction`s in your single, centralized call to `Mapper.Initialize()`

### `AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure()` in `Application_Start()` becomes

```
Mapper.Initialize(x =>
            {
                Project1.AutoMapperConfiguration.ConfigAction.Invoke(x);
                Project2.AutoMapperConfiguration.ConfigAction.Invoke(x);
                Project3.AutoMapperConfiguration.ConfigAction.Invoke(x);
                //... keep adding as your project grows
            });
```

This eliminates the need to copy-and-paste the method body from each separate `Mapper.Initialize()` call into your central call. **DRY** and all that.

Answer (score 6):

To update @theyetiman's brilliant answer for AutoMapper 5.2 & .NET Core.

```
public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(ConfigAction);
    }

    public static Action<IMapperConfigurationExpression> ConfigAction = cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile<SomeProfile>();            
        cfg.AddProfile<SomeOtherProfileProfile>();
    };
}
```

API or web startup.

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    Mapper.Initialize(x =>
    {
        Project1.AutoMapperConfiguration.ConfigAction.Invoke(x);
        Project2.AutoMapperConfiguration.ConfigAction.Invoke(x);
        Project3.AutoMapperConfiguration.ConfigAction.Invoke(x);
    });
}
```