# Is there a better way of running the automapper once the application start?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I did put my mapping literally inside the `Application_Start()` just like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

  WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
  FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
  RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
  BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
  AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();

  Mapper.CreateMap<Item, StockItems>(); <-- Here
}
```

Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825244/where-to-place-automapper-createmaps

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that when you say "better", you're accepting alternatives? If so, if the performance hit is acceptable, you can use `DynamicMap<TSource, TDestination>(TSource)` whenever you need to map. This prevents having to create mappings:

```
var stockItem = Mapper.DynamicMap<Item, StockItems>(item);
```

Comment: Wow! Didn't know you could do this. Thanks mate. What's the difference with `Mapper.Create` to `Mapper.DynamicMap`? I would really love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: @BoyPasmo Basically, `DynamicMap` both creates a mapping configuration and maps the object, whereas `Map` requires you to call `CreateMap` first. To be honest, I'm not sure if AutoMapper internally caches the configuration on a call to `DynamicMap` which is why you should be aware of the performance implications in a per-request scenario.