# How to use AutoMapper with PagedList?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper, pagedlist

I'd like to use AutoMapper in order to map my ViewModel to domain model class. Also I'm using PagedList NuGet Package. I'm using it this way:

```
[Authorize]
[AutoMap(typeof(ErrorsLog), typeof(ErrorsLogViewModel))]
public ActionResult Errors(string searchString, string currentFilter, int? page)
{
    if (searchString != null)
    {
        page = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        searchString = currentFilter;
    }

    var el = _er.GetErrorsLog();
    ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        el = el.Where(s => s.ErrorSource.Contains(searchString));
    }

    const int pageSize = 3;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
    return View("Errors", el.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

Unfortunately I got error:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. Mapping types: ErrorsLog -> ErrorsLogViewModel DigitalHubOnlineStore.Models.ErrorsLog -> DigitalHubOnlineStore.ViewModels.ErrorsLogViewModel Destination path: ErrorsLogViewModel Source value: PagedList.PagedList`1[DigitalHubOnlineStore.Models.ErrorsLog]

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you have register your mappings?
By the error message, it seems that you didn't call the `CreateMap` method anywhere yet.
Take a look at [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started#how-do-i-use-automapper).

**EDIT**

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825244/where-to-place-automapper-createmaps/6825394#6825394), you can create a static class for your mappings...

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
   public static void Configure()
   {    
      Mapper.CreateMap<ErrorsLog, ErrorsLogViewModel>();
   }
}
```

and just call it in your Global.asax:

```
AutoMapperConfig.Configure();
```

Comment: Yes, I did not. Where I should call this method? In controller or Global.asax?

Comment: You know, it's better to include the essential parts of the answer here (not in a link) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: You are right @ZygD, sorry! Andrey, I've edited the answer with the basic configuration needs, hope that helps!