# AutoMapper and SimpleInjector

Tags: c#

How do I register my AutoMapper class in SimpleInjector?

This is the part of my class where register Mapper SimpleInjector:

```
container.RegisterSingleton(Mapper.Configuration);
container.Register<IMapper>(**--What should I put here?--**)
```

This is my MapperConfig class:

```
public class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static MapperConfiguration RegisterMappings()
    {
        return new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(new DomainToViewModelMappingProfile());
            cfg.AddProfile(new ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: usually i call   AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure(); in my GlobalAsax.cs on app_startup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to register AutoMapper 4.2.0 with Simple Injector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370733/how-to-register-automapper-4-2-0-with-simple-injector)

Comment: Yes, as @federicoscamuzzi says, it's more typical to initialise AutoMapper in AppStart => `public static class AutomapperConfig { // static configuration class e.g. Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {...}) }`

Comment: OK, but if I would not be using ASP.Net, if I would be using a Desktop application or Console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your automapperConfig class to a static one .. like this:

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static MapperConfiguration RegisterMappings()
    {
        return new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(new DomainToViewModelMappingProfile());
            cfg.AddProfile(new ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile());
        });
    }
}
```

then call it in your GlobalAsax.cs file in App_start like this:

```
 public class WebApiApplication : HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);


            // Register Mapping Configuration on Start up
            AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();

        }

        protected void Application_End()
        {
            //Cleanup all resources

        }
    }
```

Comment: OK, but if I would not be using ASP.Net, if I would be using a Desktop application or Console

Comment: try to find the equivalent of App_start for your console or WPF application ..also maybe in your Program.cs at first line you can call  AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();