# How to initialize automapper in vb.net global.asax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, automapper-5

I'm trying to initialize Automapper in Global.asax file using vb.net in ASP.NET API Version 2.0. I'm using Auto Mapper version 5.2. I can initialize using the C# code but I am not so sure about the VB.Net. After googling I've found something and here is what I'm trying now:

```
Module AutoMapperConfiguration
Public MapperConfiguration As IMapper
Public Sub Configure()
    Dim config = New MapperConfiguration(//in this line I'm getting an error:
```

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called with these arguments:
>       'Public Overloads Sub New(configurationExpression As MapperConfigurationExpression)': Lambda expression cannot be converted to 'MapperConfigurationExpression' because 'MapperConfigurationExpression' is not a delegate type.

```
        Sub(cfg)
            cfg.AddProfile(New EntityMapProfile())
        End Sub)
    MapperConfiguration = config.CreateMapper()
 End Sub
End Module
```

Then I've called this module from the Application_Start()

```
  AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure()
```

Here I'm not facing any error but on the previous line I'm facing error which is causing the issue.
But last time I've done this using C# with the following line of code in the global.asax file

```
  Mapper.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile<EntityMapProfile>();
        });
```

Under Application_Start() which worked nicely but now even if I convert those above lines of code then still I'm facing issues. 
Here, I would like to mention that I've found the VB.Net code from the following  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825244/where-to-place-automapper-createmaps) I would appreciate if any one can help or suggest me on the above. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The VB equivalent of this C#:

```
Mapper.Initialize(x =>
    {
        x.AddProfile<EntityMapProfile>();
    });
```

is this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(Sub(x)
        x.AddProfile(Of EntityMapProfile)()
    End Sub)
```

Did you try that?

Comment: Here's the def of the profile that works with the code above


Public Class EntityMapProfile
    Inherits Profile
    
    Public sub New() 
            CreateMap(Of BudgetChangeRequest, BCRViewModel)()
    End sub

End Class