# How to register Automapper into vb.net global.asax file?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I've a ASP.NET API Version 2.0 with VB.Net in back end where I'm trying to initialize Automapper in Global.asax file. Here, I'm using Auto Mapper version 5.2. I can initialize using the C# code but I am not so sure about the VB.Net. After googling I've found [something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825244/where-to-place-automapper-createmaps) and here is what I'm trying now:

```
Module AutoMapperConfiguration
 Public MapperConfiguration As IMapper
  Public Sub Configure()
  Dim config = New MapperConfiguration(//in this line I'm getting an error:
```

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called with these arguments: 'Public Overloads Sub New(configurationExpression As MapperConfigurationExpression)': Lambda expression cannot be converted to 'MapperConfigurationExpression' because 'MapperConfigurationExpression' is not a delegate type.

```
              Sub(cfg)
            cfg.AddProfile(New EntityMapProfile())
        End Sub)
    MapperConfiguration = config.CreateMapper()
End Sub
```

End Module

Then I've called this module from the Application_Start()

```
 AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure()
```

But last time I've done this using C# with the following line of code in the global.asax file

```
 Mapper.Initialize(x =>
    {
        x.AddProfile<EntityMapProfile>();
    });
```

Under Application_Start() which worked nicely but now even if I convert those above lines of code then still I'm facing issues. I would appreciate your help or suggestion on the above.

Comment: Didn't you just post this question?

Comment: Yes, but sorry for that I was unable to retrieve this account password and that one is a new account so I'm going to close that topic. I guess that one no one will notice and I really need help on this urgently. Thanks

Comment: I think it expects a return value. Try `Function` instead of `Sub` for your lambda.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but just now I've tried with function and return value but still the error remains the same.

Comment: I've tried that as well. Actually the error is highlighting that I'm missing the parameters. But I'm not so sure what to put into the parameters.

Comment: It looks like what you have should work from what I see on GitHub. `public MapperConfiguration(Action<IMapperConfigurationExpression> configure)`. You may want to actually set it to a variable and pass it in because it is definitely hitting the wrong constructor

Comment: Could you please help me to explain this more with an example?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/c9xfhk66

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working now. You really saved my day. Please send it here as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For whatever reason VB.NET is not using the correct constructor when you inline the `Sub` for the Action.

```
Module AutoMapperConfiguration
    Public MapperConfiguration As IMapper

    Public Sub Configure()
        Dim configAction As Action(Of IMapperConfigurationExpression) = Sub(cfg) cfg.AddProfile(Of EntityMapProfile)()
        Dim config = New MapperConfiguration(configAction)

        MapperConfiguration = config
    End Sub

End Module
```

The above will force your lambda to the correct type of `Action(Of IMapperConfigurationExpression)` and thereby force VB.NET to use the correct constructor overload.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation and nice answer. It really saved me a lot of time.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. That's kind of a pain and unexpected.